# Any rule of thumb that says any reasonable function I can write down is measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Question arose in the context of probability: If $Y$ is $F-$measurable and $h$ is some function, $h(Y)$ is $F-$measurable if $h$ is a measurable function (Doob-Dynkin).

For example, let $f(x,y)$ be the joint density function of random variables $X$ and $Y$, $g(x)$ be some integrable function, and $h(y)=\int g(x)f(x,y)\,dx/\int f(x,y)\,dx$; then $h(y)$ is measurable - I wondered if there is some rule of thumb that tells me this quickly, since I remembered someone saying, "Any function you can write down is measurable."

Thanks!

Comment: When one says "Any functions you can write down is measurable", he often refers to the fact that [all functions being **Lebesgue**-measurable is consistent with Zermelo-Fraenkel (without the axiom choice)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133999/can-one-construct-a-non-measurable-set-without-axiom-of-choice). Of course, this needs not hold for the **general** definition of measurable function between arbitrary mensural spaces.

Comment: There is a theorem that says any constructive function is continuous. (There is a feature of the constructive reals which keeps you from defining functions piecewise.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: One doesn't have to go so far to full constructivism, otherwise as you note we don't even have piecewise functions, which we certainly know how to write down!

Comment: Which is why I wrote a comment, not an answer. @user21820 But it means that if you write something which is piecewise something computable, then it is piecewise continuous and hence measurable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: What you say implies that computable implies piecewise continuous, presumably with countably many pieces. Is that really so?

Comment: that's not what I wrote. There is no computable discontinuous on the reals. If a function is piecewise computable, then it is measurable. @user21820

Comment: Oh I see. I forgot that; I'd a different idea of "computable", which wasn't the right one.