# Can we pick representatives from the "difference is rational" equivalence classes?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, logic, real-numbers, equivalence-relations

Let us define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by saying that $x\sim y$ if $x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$?  This equivalence relation partitions $\mathbb{R}$ into uncountably many equivalence classes.  My question  is, is it possible to construct a set which has exactly one element from each of these equivalence classes?

Can we define these elements explicitly?  Or failing that, can we at least prove that there exists a definable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which has this property?  What about a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You need the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133999/243089

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a set is a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).  It is non-measurable (and in particular not Borel).  Solovay showed it is consistent with ZF (without Axiom of Choice) that all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are measurable.  Therefore without some form of Axiom of Choice it is impossible to construct such a set and prove it has the desired property.

Comment: That's not quite accurate. Solovay showed that ZF + DC + "All sets are measurable" is consistent *relative to ZFC + an inaccessible*, not relative to ZFC alone - and Shelah [later showed](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760522) that that was optimal. However, pre-Solovay it was known that ZF + "All sets are measurable" is equiconsistent with ZFC (although in the absence of DC, "measurable" is a bit funny ...); I believe this was proved by Truss.

Comment: Actually, after searching for a citation I can't back up my claim about pre-Solovay knowledge.